# Confirming File upload directory traversal without knowing upload path or being able to retrieve the uploaded file?

Tags: web-application, file-upload, directory-traversal

I am faced with a file upload functionality. We can upload docs and png's but cannot view them.
I have tested for several things so far and now would like to test for directory traversal via file name.
I.e if can I upload / replace files in other directory's using a modified file name.

From my understanding, in an insecure app, if we upload the file `../../../test.txt`, it would upload to a directory 3 levels down. i.e

```
www.testapp.com/test1/test2/test3/uploads/../../../test.txt
```

is equivalent to:

```
www.testapp.com/test1/test.txt
```

This is great if we know where the upload directory is. I currently don't know where the files are being uploaded to, and don't have access to the filesystem.

Is there a way I could verify if this vulnerability is present on the web application?

Comment: Down? or Up the file tree?

Comment: 1. can you get any feedback about the cwd at any point? 2. do you know where you want to end up? 3. have you tried "overshooting" (i.e. `../../../../../../../../../../../../tmp`) 4. have you considered the impact of a `chroot`? 5. In your OSCP, you could upload a shell and get access to the file system. Is that sort of access possible? 6. If all you want to do is to verify that dir traversal is possible, do you need to know the path?

Comment: Have you consulted the various cheatsheets for ideas? https://github.com/JahTheTrueGod/Directory-Traversal-Cheat-Sheet and https://pentestlab.blog/2012/06/29/directory-traversal-cheat-sheet/ and https://akimbocore.com/article/linux-path-traversal-cheat-sheet/ for example?